# Found red brick powder near the floor in the basement after a few months -- is this dangerous?

Tags: basement, masonry

https://imgur.com/a/Dyiorst

See album link above for pictures.

Seems like my basement bricks are disintegrating. I see red powder near the walls and the bricks of the basement seem flaky. When I pressed on them near the fingers, flakes came down.

My hypothesis is that this is due to water damage. Even though I have concrete all around the basement walls of the house, and I tried to make sure it is sloping away, maybe there are gaps between the basement walls and concrete floor outside such that water leaks in.

My questions:

1. What is this condition called?
2. Will this cause long term damage to the basement/house?
3. How do I prevent this from happening?
4. What type of contractor can fix this?

Comment: Is the brick in contact with soil on the other side? An image shows a concrete vertical surface that's wet. Where did that moisture come from? Is the basement protected from frost during the winter?

Comment: It does not have contact with the soil. It has concrete driveway on the other side, but there may be a small gap between the wall and the driveway where the moisture is coming from. Actually the image is misleading as that concrete is not that wet -- it is just a bit different in color (it's not wet to the touch).

Comment: that concrete looks saturated. Saturated brick plus freezing could cause the spalling. Your driveway doesn't seem relevant to soil on the other side. Are you saying that there is soil on the other side, but it's unlikely to be very wet? Is there a layer of concrete between the surface of the brick and soil, with the concrete touching the soil? Or is that brick wall actually above ground?